# Couldnt set Width to Combobox in ZK?

Tags: zk

Am new to ZK and using **combobox** in my page.I gave `width="100%"` to **combobox** but it doesn't take and if I refresh the page , the **combobox** shrinks.

Please anyone tell me how I can set common width to entire `combobox` in my application uniformly?

Comment: Read carefully http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/UI_Patterns/Hflex_and_Vflex

Comment: Use `hflex` is also a good way and it is recommended.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do what you want. for example:

```
<div sclass="positionInfo">
    <combobox readonly="true" width="30%" model="@load(vm.positionModel)" constraint="no empty:Please select position!"
              selectedItem="@bind(fx.position)" tabindex="3"> 
        <template name="model" var="po"> 
            <comboitem label="@load(po.positionName)" value="@load(po.positionId)" /> 
        </template> 
    </combobox>
</div>
```

put your combobox inside div element, then set CSS class named "positionInfo".

set CSS rule for CSS selector `.positionInfo` (width by a specific pixels or percent), then everything will be done.